# returning an array on a getter function not working in PHP

Tags: php

I'm pretty new to php and am trying a basic project. I have a Person class to store names of people.

I want my setName($name) setter to keep a list of names a person has had and my getName() function to return the list of names.

My code is as follows: Person.php

```
class Person() {

  private $name;
  private $names=array();

  public function Person() {
    $this->name=NULL;
  }

  function setName($newName) {
    $names[] = $newName;
  }

  function getName() {
    return $this->names;
  }

}
```

I get an empty array returned when I call getName from another file after setting a name. I am not sure if the scope is correct. Could anybody help out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're missing `$this->` in this line. So you're pushing into a local variable instead of the class' member `$names`.

```
function setName($newName) {
    $this->names[] = $newName;
}
```

Comment: That works when setting names, I get the following array returned:                                                              
Array
(
    [0] => Garfield
    [1] => Simba
)